# Getting error on updating PHP from 5.2 to 7

Tags: php, updates

When I am updating PHP version on server from 5.2 to 7, I am getting following errors:

```
[30-Jun-2020 00:52:29 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: magickwand: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20151012
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
[30-Jun-2020 00:52:29 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: imagick: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20151012
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
[30-Jun-2020 00:52:29 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/php52/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/pdo.so' - /opt/php52/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/pdo.so: undefined symbol: zend_objects_store_add_ref in Unknown on line 0
[30-Jun-2020 00:52:29 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_sqlite: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20151012
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
[30-Jun-2020 00:52:29 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/php52/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/sqlite.so' - /opt/php52/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/sqlite.so: undefined symbol: third_arg_force_ref in Unknown on line 0
[30-Jun-2020 00:52:29 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_mysql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20151012
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
[30-Jun-2020 00:52:29 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: SourceGuardian: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20151012
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
[30-Jun-2020 00:52:29 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Directive 'allow_call_time_pass_reference' is no longer available in PHP in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: You need to update all of your extensions, too

Comment: @JohnConde updated PHP using MultiPHP Manager,

Comment: How to update extensions?